# Call javascript function result outside function

Tags: javascript

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
   console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
   port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
});
```

I want to use 'port' outside this Chrome API function, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you try to pass port variable to another method instead of calling it immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

either call a function after the response to pass value to it:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
   console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
   port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
   callback(port);

});

function callback(value){
   console.log(value); //accessed value outside that function
}
```

OR

create a global variable and assign the reponse to it

```
var portValue;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
   console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
   port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
   portValue = port;

});
```

Depends on how you want to use the value, you can adapt any of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
var currentPort;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
   console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
   port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
   currentPort = port;
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined

CODE:

var currentPort;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
  
  //function aanroepen(){
  //  port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
  //}
  port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
  currentPort = port;
}); 
 currentPort.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});

Comment: Looks like you are trying to call `postMessage` on `currentPort` before the listener has been called.

Answer (score 0):

```
someFunction function(){
    return chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
     console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
     port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
     return port;

});

var port = someFunction();
```